# Multiple triggers not working in Quartz.NET

Tags: c#, quartz.net

The Jobs run separately without problems.. when trying to add 2 triggers to one job the program doesn't do anything.

What is the problem here?

```
            IJobDetail Job = JobBuilder.Create<Job>()
            .WithIdentity("Job")
            .Build();

            ITrigger JobStartUpTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("JobStartUpTrigger")
            .StartNow()
            .ForJob(Job)
            .Build();

            ITrigger JobCronTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("JobCronTrigger")
            .WithCronSchedule("0 30 9 ? * SAT")
            .ForJob(Job)
            .Build();

            _scheduler.ScheduleJob(JobStartUpTrigger);
            _scheduler.ScheduleJob(JobCronTrigger);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to fix the problem:

```
            IJobDetail Job = JobBuilder.Create<Job>()
            .WithIdentity("Job", "group1")
            .Build();

            IList<ITrigger> triggers = new List<ITrigger>();

            ITrigger JobStartUpTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("JobStartUpTrigger", "group1")
            .StartNow()
            .Build();

            ITrigger JobCronTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("JobCronTrigger" , "group1")
            .WithCronSchedule("0 30 9 ? * SAT")
            .Build();

            triggers.Add(JobStartUpTrigger);
            triggers.Add(JobCronTrigger);

            IReadOnlyCollection<ITrigger> listOfTriggers = new ReadOnlyCollection<ITrigger>(triggers);

            _scheduler.ScheduleJob(Job, listOfTriggers, true);
```